# Is it safe to use email encoders? Or how is it safest to show email address?

Tags: java, php, html, email

Services like : http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html encodes email to ASCII. Is it totally safe? Can spammers copy this code and decode it?

**They can decode it, so how is it safest to show your email on the website? Probably by putting it in the image?**

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whatever you encode with an algorithm that a human being can then decode easily, another algorithm can decode just as easily. It even says on the bottom of the linked page that it's not secure.

Comment: It is just html entities by the looks of it so yes, try base64 encoding.

Comment: Yes, of course they can. The question is what's the likelihood of them doing it? Any encoding, including BASE64, BTW @Sammaye

Comment: @Icarus Base64 was just a starting point, its still better than html entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not safe at all. You are still exposing your email address on the page. Some dumb spiders will end confused, but those which are up to date will definitely be able to "decode" these entities quickly. The only solution is to... not expose email address at all. If you use contact form with recipients to be chosen by users, use IDs and dereference it in your code. If you need to show email - show image, but if anyone would like to have you address in their spam DB, then he can always put it by hand there.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no, it is not fully secure as it can easily be decoded by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone could easily decode this using an ASCII table, like so: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

A clever spam bot can trivially read the "hidden" address.

What you should do instead, is have something like (for john.doe@gmail.com):

```
john (dot) doe (at) gmail (dot) com
```

One could still construct a bot to counter this, but it would be impractical as this technique isn't very common.

Truth be told, there's no 100% way of hidhing your email. Even images have OCRs, and in the worst case, a persistent human can always manually type your address and add it to his to-spam list.

If you want your users to contact you, the best way would be to make a form, and have **the server** to process the request and send you an email. This way, your address is not exposed to anyone.

Comment: @arasmussen: Like I said, I could easily make a bot to counter this, but this not being a very common technique, not many existing bots will figure it out :)

Comment: I've seen it used everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is not to show the email address at all. If you want your users to be able to send emails to each other, write a dedicated UI where they can type the message in and send the email directly from your server. But make sure that the UI itself is secured with login/pass too, otherwise you're back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

That method would be safe against some - but not all spiders. If even one got through, you could be introducing the user to thousands of emails of spam. I guess it's up to you whether it's worth the risk, but I definitely wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this form of email encoding is very weak in terms of security, in fact, it is not design for security purposes at all. It's encoding, not encrypting.